# Why my precision getting loss while converting double to float in c#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, precision

I' having double value as **10293.01416015625** in c# and i'm trying to convert to float. Since float has only 24 bits, i suppose to get the result as **10293.0141**. But i'm getting value as **10293.0137**

```
double value = 10293.01416015625;
float converted = (float)value;
```

**Expected value** - 10293.0141

**Value am getting** - 10293.0137

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [System.Single documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netcore-3.1):

> A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

Your result is correct up to 7 significant digits (10293.01). You shouldn't expect to be able to get more than that with `float`.

The exact value of the `float`s closest to 10293.01416015625 are 10293.013671875 and 10293.0146484375. Both are exactly 0.00048828125 away from the value you're trying to represent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If am adding 2 at end of the value like 10293.014160156252, am getting correct value. What will be the reason for this?

Comment: @VenkyDhana: As per my edit, the value you're requesting is exactly half way between two `float` values. Your change pushes it towards the higher one, which in this case *happens* to be the answer you're expecting. But fundamentally you just shouldn't be using `float` if you need more than 7 decimal digits of precision.